# Stuck with comparing an random generated string with game object name/tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Developing a small game where random name will be generated showing on the text space and player should collide with object of the name shown in the text space. For example if "lemon" is shown then player should touch the lemon gameobject placed on table.

```
   using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    public class RandomString : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] Text randName;
        public GameObject[] veggies;
        string[] veg = { "Olive", "Lemon", "Carrot" };
    
        void Start()
        {
            randName.text = veg[1];
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            GenerateRandom(3);
    
        }
        private void GenerateRandom(int maxInt)
        {
            int rnd = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, maxInt);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                string a =  veg[rnd];
                randName.text = a;
    
            }
        }
        void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col, string a)
        {
            if (col.gameObject.CompareTag(a))
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you constantly generate a new random value even though you only need one inside of the `if(Input.GetKey)` block ...

Then also: do you really want to assign a new random every frame the button stays pressed? Wouldn't the first time be enough (`GetKeyDown`)?

And then you can't just change the signature of `OnCollisionEnter(Collider)` otherwise this message method is not recognized by Unity and not called.

I think it should rather be

```
// Store the random string in class scope
string a;

private void Start()
{
    GenerateRandom ();
}

private void Update()
{
    // While debugging I assume you will use this
    // otherwise there is no need later to call the method continuously
    // Only generate one new random for each press of Space
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        GenerateRandom();
    }
}

public void GenerateRandom()
{
    // You only need a random index if you are actually gonna use it
    // Note I would get rid of the additional tags array and rather 
    // directly use the tags of given objects!
    // This way you can't mess them up and can easily add more
    int rnd = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, veggies.Length);
    a =  veggies[rnd].tag;
    randName.text = a;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    // Use the "a" stored in class scope not a parameter
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag(a))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");

        // Little addition from my side
        // You could probably directly generate the next random after a match
        // so you wouldn't need the button and Update at all
        GenerateRandom();
    }
}
```

Instead of using the tags at all you could actually also rather use the object references and their names directly:

```
GameObject a;

private void GenerateRandom()
{
    int rnd = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, veggies.Length);
    a =  veggies[rnd];
    randName.text = a.name;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject == a)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");

        GenerateRandom();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the value without the update function? The collision is happening only after i press the spacebar once

Comment: @user3437968 yes sure! In `Start` call `GenerateRandom` once ;)

Comment: Thank you so much.